# Why I can't fetch this page using php curl?

Tags: php, curl

```
<?php
  $ch = curl_init("https://www.snai.it/sport");    // initialize curl handle
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    print($data);

?>
```

I wan't to fetch this page using php curl.it gives the empty response and there is no error in the console I don't know what is going wrong any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What you want to fetch from this page please specify more.

Comment: Please check for the domain/page that you are trying to get content. I think the domain/page that you are trying may be not working.

Comment: I have updated my question.I want to fetch sport page in the given url.

Comment: use a basic example http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php and add `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);` for ssl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your url redirects to a secured page (i.e. https page). Probably you do not have any ssl support for your curl. I used verbose mode `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);` and it came on response:

```
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Location: https://www.snai.it/
< Connection: close
```

Comment: Thanks you.I found the solution.

Answer (score 1):

`curl_exec()` returns `TRUE` on success or `FALSE` on failure by default.

If you want to get the result/data from the given URL you will need to set the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option.

So add following line before `curl_exec()`.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

As mentioned by @Sabuj one will also need to add following to fetch the redirect secure page.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
```

Comment: Still no output empty response.